# Why are there two interior regions in this diagram?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, kerr-metric, white-holes

[image]

Why are there two interior regions in this diagram? There seems to be two inner horizons, and two wormhole regions.
Where do the two such regions comes from? What determines which reason someone falls into? Could a composite body fall into "both regions" with part of it going into one region and part into the other.
The diagram seems to indicate that if you're precise enough you can fall almost directly from the Black hole to the white hole while spending an arbitrarily small amount of time in either of the Wormhole regions.

Answer (score 0):

> [Blademan9999](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/773890/24093) asked: "*What determines which reason someone falls into?*"

> [Madore](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/math/kerr.html#videos.lazy-geodesic) wrote: "*If one is traveling along a geodeisc (i.e., freely falling), then the condition is simple: it is the ratio of angular momentum (as measured along the black hole's axis: this is a conserved quantity) to energy that determines whether the particle enters one or the other region III.*"

It depends on your combination of kinetic energy and angular momentum when you cross the surface if you land in the region or the parallel region, and in which ones of those.

For example, in free fall from infinity (with the negative escape velocity and no covariant angular momentum) your worldline goes through the regular regions.

If you cross the parallel inner horizon, you get infinite blueshift of all the light that will ever fall into the black hole from the universe outside.

If you cross the regular inner horizon you get infinite blueshift from inside, either the collapsed star or the eternal parallel universe (as you can see in the Penrose diagram you posted).

With the inner antihorizons it is the other way around: infinite blueshift from the universe at the regular inner antihorizon, and from the parallel universe at the parallel one.

The flow of proper time relative to coordinate time in the region is also opposite to that in the corresponding parallel region.